# JavaFX изменить размер ImageVIew

Tags: java, javafx, gui

Всем привет.

Уже много инфы перелопатил и решил написать сюда

**Вопрос:** Как изменить размер ImageView простым растягиванием края изображения. т.е. способом как это делается в С# например (такое же можно наблюдать в фотошопе или пэинте например) [image: вот примерная схема как должно быть]

На эвентах mouseOnPressed & mouseOnDragged у меня уже повешены перемешение по рабочему столу

Заранее благодарен за ответ

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ на свой вопрос в виде вот этого [кода](https://github.com/varren/JavaFX-Resizable-Draggable-Node/blob/master/src/sample/DragResizeMod.java)

***Проверил работает!!!***

Запуск вот так `DragResizeMod.makeResizable(rectangle, null)`

```
public class DragResizeMod {
public interface OnDragResizeEventListener {
    void onDrag(Node node, double x, double y, double h, double w);

    void onResize(Node node, double x, double y, double h, double w);
}

private static final OnDragResizeEventListener defaultListener = new OnDragResizeEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDrag(Node node, double x, double y, double h, double w) {
        /*
        // TODO find generic way to get parent width and height of any node
        // can perform out of bounds check here if you know your parent size
        if (x > width - w ) x = width - w;
        if (y > height - h) y = height - h;
        if (x < 0) x = 0;
        if (y < 0) y = 0;
        */
        setNodeSize(node, x, y, h, w);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResize(Node node, double x, double y, double h, double w) {
        /*
        // TODO find generic way to get parent width and height of any node
        // can perform out of bounds check here if you know your parent size
        if (w > width - x) w = width - x;
        if (h > height - y) h = height - y;
        if (x < 0) x = 0;
        if (y < 0) y = 0;
        */
        setNodeSize(node, x, y, h, w);
    }

    private void setNodeSize(Node node, double x, double y, double h, double w) {
        node.setLayoutX(x);
        node.setLayoutY(y);
        // TODO find generic way to set width and height of any node
        // here we cant set height and width to node directly.
        // or i just cant find how to do it,
        // so you have to wright resize code anyway for your Nodes...
        //something like this
        if (node instanceof Canvas) {
            ((Canvas) node).setWidth(w);
            ((Canvas) node).setHeight(h);
        } else if (node instanceof Rectangle) {
            ((Rectangle) node).setWidth(w);
            ((Rectangle) node).setHeight(h);
        }
    }
};

public static enum S {
    DEFAULT,
    DRAG,
    NW_RESIZE,
    SW_RESIZE,
    NE_RESIZE,
    SE_RESIZE,
    E_RESIZE,
    W_RESIZE,
    N_RESIZE,
    S_RESIZE;
}


private double clickX, clickY, nodeX, nodeY, nodeH, nodeW;

private S state = S.DEFAULT;

private Node node;
private OnDragResizeEventListener listener = defaultListener;

private static final int MARGIN = 8;
private static final double MIN_W = 30;
private static final double MIN_H = 20;

private DragResizeMod(Node node, OnDragResizeEventListener listener) {
    this.node = node;
    if (listener != null)
        this.listener = listener;
}

public static void makeResizable(Node node) {
    makeResizable(node, null);
}

public static void makeResizable(Node node, OnDragResizeEventListener listener) {
    final DragResizeMod resizer = new DragResizeMod(node, listener);

    node.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            resizer.mousePressed(event);
        }
    });
    node.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            resizer.mouseDragged(event);
        }
    });
    node.setOnMouseMoved(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            resizer.mouseOver(event);
        }
    });
    node.setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            resizer.mouseReleased(event);
        }
    });
}

protected void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {
    node.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
    state = S.DEFAULT;
}

protected void mouseOver(MouseEvent event) {
    S state = currentMouseState(event);
    Cursor cursor = getCursorForState(state);
    node.setCursor(cursor);
}

private S currentMouseState(MouseEvent event) {
    S state = S.DEFAULT;
    boolean left = isLeftResizeZone(event);
    boolean right = isRightResizeZone(event);
    boolean top = isTopResizeZone(event);
    boolean bottom = isBottomResizeZone(event);

    if (left && top) state = S.NW_RESIZE;
    else if (left && bottom) state = S.SW_RESIZE;
    else if (right && top) state = S.NE_RESIZE;
    else if (right && bottom) state = S.SE_RESIZE;
    else if (right) state = S.E_RESIZE;
    else if (left) state = S.W_RESIZE;
    else if (top) state = S.N_RESIZE;
    else if (bottom) state = S.S_RESIZE;
    else if (isInDragZone(event)) state = S.DRAG;

    return state;
}

private static Cursor getCursorForState(S state) {
    switch (state) {
        case NW_RESIZE:
            return Cursor.NW_RESIZE;
        case SW_RESIZE:
            return Cursor.SW_RESIZE;
        case NE_RESIZE:
            return Cursor.NE_RESIZE;
        case SE_RESIZE:
            return Cursor.SE_RESIZE;
        case E_RESIZE:
            return Cursor.E_RESIZE;
        case W_RESIZE:
            return Cursor.W_RESIZE;
        case N_RESIZE:
            return Cursor.N_RESIZE;
        case S_RESIZE:
            return Cursor.S_RESIZE;
        default:
            return Cursor.MOVE;
    }
}


protected void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event) {

    if (listener != null) {
        double mouseX = parentX(event.getX());
        double mouseY = parentY(event.getY());
        if (state == S.DRAG) {
            listener.onDrag(node, mouseX - clickX, mouseY - clickY, nodeH, nodeW);
        } else if (state != S.DEFAULT) {
            //resizing
            double newX = nodeX;
            double newY = nodeY;
            double newH = nodeH;
            double newW = nodeW;

            // Right Resize
            if (state == S.E_RESIZE || state == S.NE_RESIZE || state == S.SE_RESIZE) {
                newW = mouseX - nodeX;
            }
            // Left Resize
            if (state == S.W_RESIZE || state == S.NW_RESIZE || state == S.SW_RESIZE) {
                newX = mouseX;
                newW = nodeW + nodeX - newX;
            }

            // Bottom Resize
            if (state == S.S_RESIZE || state == S.SE_RESIZE || state == S.SW_RESIZE) {
                newH = mouseY - nodeY;
            }
            // Top Resize
            if (state == S.N_RESIZE || state == S.NW_RESIZE || state == S.NE_RESIZE) {
                newY = mouseY;
                newH = nodeH + nodeY - newY;
            }

            //min valid rect Size Check
            if (newW < MIN_W) {
                if (state == S.W_RESIZE || state == S.NW_RESIZE || state == S.SW_RESIZE)
                    newX = newX - MIN_W + newW;
                newW = MIN_W;
            }

            if (newH < MIN_H) {
                if (state == S.N_RESIZE || state == S.NW_RESIZE || state == S.NE_RESIZE)
                    newY = newY + newH - MIN_H;
                newH = MIN_H;
            }

            listener.onResize(node, newX, newY, newH, newW);
        }
    }
}

protected void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {

    if (isInResizeZone(event)) {
        setNewInitialEventCoordinates(event);
        state = currentMouseState(event);
    } else if (isInDragZone(event)) {
        setNewInitialEventCoordinates(event);
        state = S.DRAG;
    } else {
        state = S.DEFAULT;
    }
}

private void setNewInitialEventCoordinates(MouseEvent event) {
    nodeX = nodeX();
    nodeY = nodeY();
    nodeH = nodeH();
    nodeW = nodeW();
    clickX = event.getX();
    clickY = event.getY();
}

private boolean isInResizeZone(MouseEvent event) {
    return isLeftResizeZone(event) || isRightResizeZone(event)
            || isBottomResizeZone(event) || isTopResizeZone(event);
}

private boolean isInDragZone(MouseEvent event) {
    double xPos = parentX(event.getX());
    double yPos = parentY(event.getY());
    double nodeX = nodeX() + MARGIN;
    double nodeY = nodeY() + MARGIN;
    double nodeX0 = nodeX() + nodeW() - MARGIN;
    double nodeY0 = nodeY() + nodeH() - MARGIN;

    return (xPos > nodeX && xPos < nodeX0) && (yPos > nodeY && yPos < nodeY0);
}

private boolean isLeftResizeZone(MouseEvent event) {
    return intersect(0, event.getX());
}

private boolean isRightResizeZone(MouseEvent event) {
    return intersect(nodeW(), event.getX());
}

private boolean isTopResizeZone(MouseEvent event) {
    return intersect(0, event.getY());
}

private boolean isBottomResizeZone(MouseEvent event) {
    return intersect(nodeH(), event.getY());
}

private boolean intersect(double side, double point) {
    return side + MARGIN > point && side - MARGIN < point;
}

private double parentX(double localX) {
    return nodeX() + localX;
}

private double parentY(double localY) {
    return nodeY() + localY;
}

private double nodeX() {
    return node.getBoundsInParent().getMinX();
}

private double nodeY() {
    return node.getBoundsInParent().getMinY();
}

private double nodeW() {
    return node.getBoundsInParent().getWidth();
}

private double nodeH() {
    return node.getBoundsInParent().getHeight();
}
```

}